# How to fix reset type input doesn't really resets all forms?

Tags: php, html, css

I am facing a problem with a form that has reset input type, and want to reset / clear all forms value when resset button is clicked. But unfortunately my reset button doesn't really reset all forms value, there is an input form that isn't reseted well, i mean still remain some value in that form. How to really reset all of that values ?

```
<form name="frm" action="?mod=<?php echo($_GET["mod"]); ?>" method="post">
   <div class="panelcontainer" style="width: 100%;">
   <h3><div style="display: block; float: left;"><div style="clear: both;"></div>FILTER DATA PENCARIAN</div><input type="button" value="+" style="float: right; display: block; font-weight: bold; width:40px;" id="expand" /><div style="clear: both;"></div></h3>
       <div class="bodypanel" id="bodyfilter">
           <table border="0px" cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='100%'>
               <tr>
                   <td width='20%'>Nomor Register</td>
                   <td width='10px'>:</td>
                   <td>
                       <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo($_POST["id"]); ?>" />
                   </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td width='20%'>Nomor Surat</td>
                   <td width='10px'>:</td>
                   <td>
                       <input type="text" name="no_surat" value="<?php echo($_POST["no_surat"]); ?>" />
                   </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td width='20%'>Tanggal Surat</td>
                   <td width='10px'>:</td>
                   <td>
                       <input type="text" name="tgl_surat_dari" id="tgl_surat_dari" class="ufilter" value="<?php echo($_POST["tgl_surat_dari"]); ?>" />
                       S/D
                       <input type="text" name="tgl_surat_sampai" id="tgl_surat_sampai" class="ufilter" value="<?php echo($_POST["tgl_surat_sampai"]); ?>" />
                   </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                    <td width='20%'>Tanggal Pengiriman</td>
                    <td width='10px'>:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="tgl_terima_dari" id="tgl_terima_dari" class="ufilter" value="<?php echo($_POST["tgl_terima_dari"]); ?>" />
                         S/D
                        <input type="text" name="tgl_terima_sampai" id="tgl_terima_sampai" class="ufilter" value="<?php echo($_POST["tgl_terima_sampai"]); ?>" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width='20%'>Perihal</td>
                    <td width='10px'>:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="perihal_surat" value="<?php echo($_POST["perihal_surat"]); ?>" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width='20%'>Deskripsi Surat</td>
                    <td width='10px'>:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="deskripsi_surat" value="<?php echo($_POST["deskripsi_surat"]); ?>" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width='20%'>SKPD / Unit Tujuan</td>
                    <td width='10px'>:</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="id_skpd_pengirim">
                            <option value="0">[.. Pilih SKPD Tujuan ..]</option>
                            <?php
                                $res_skpd = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myapp_reftable_unitkerja ORDER BY unit_kerja ASC");
                                while($ds_skpd = mysql_fetch_array($res_skpd)){
                                    if($ds_skpd["id_unit_kerja"] == $_POST["id_skpd_pengirim"])
                                        echo("<option selected='selected' value='" . $ds_skpd["id_unit_kerja"] . "'>" . $ds_skpd["unit_kerja"] . "</option>");
                                    else
                                        echo("<option value='" . $ds_skpd["id_unit_kerja"] . "'>" . $ds_skpd["unit_kerja"] . "</option>");
                                    }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </td> 
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div class="kelang"></div>
                <table border="0px" cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='40%'>
                    <tr>
                       <td width='50%'><input type="submit" value='Filter' style="width: 100%;" /></td>
                       <td width='50%'><input type="reset" value='Reset' style="width: 100%;" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

I expect all of the values of all input forms are really reset.

The image problem is shown below :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bZKh9p13HsfzeNek_I1SK2W-u4UlmMsg/view?usp=sharing

Still remain a few of all id value. 
I expect all the values are reset.

Comment: Where is js code?

Comment: For fun and giggles, does incognito also keeps the same behaviour?

Comment: it's already resetting all input when I try. (except the select option) so what's the problem?

Comment: Also check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27309291/reset-a-form-without-javascript-input-type-reset-not-working and OPs edit: **Apparently the reset button will replace the values of all inputs with the values they had on page load. The button would clear all fields and leave them blank only if the input's value property aren't declared or are null on page load**

Comment: _“so what's the problem?”_ - most likely, simply your wrong expectation of what “reset” means. It is supposed to restore the _default values_ of the fields - and for your select field, that is the option with the `selected` attribute set.

Comment: @dooooooofai in my local, the reset button resets all the velue even the select option. but the button isn't working to reset "nomor register" after filter was clicked.

Comment: @Rahul What do you mean?

Comment: @elveti yes, how to reset the value, if the value property isn't null on page load ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace **Reset** button *HTML* code with the below code

`<input type="submit" value='Reset' style="width: 100%;" />`

2. Then place the following *PHP* code **before processing your Submit code**

`if( isset($_POST['Reset']) ){
     $_POST = array();
 }`